# MS CRM Dynamics in latest bound - how to discover all entities?

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am building a connector to CRM Dynamics.
I would like to get (discover) all the entities with their fields.
There for, I am using the **IOrganizationService** interface with RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest.
I do get all the entities names BUT I don't know how to get all **fields** (columns) of any entity.

please help...

hagai

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your almost there. This it taken from the MSDN sample: [Dump Attribute Metadata to a File.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603008.aspx)

```
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest request = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest()
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

// Retrieve the MetaData.
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(request);

foreach (EntityMetadata currentEntity in response.EntityMetadata)
{
    foreach (AttributeMetadata currentAttribute in currentEntity.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LogicalName: " + currentAttribute.LogicalName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to create `RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest` first

```
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest entityRequest = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest();
```

Then call the `service.execute()` to retrieve results

there is a [blog](http://rokhri.com/blog/how-to-get-meta-data-for-all-entities-in-crm-2011-using-ms-crm-2011-api/) post which explains really well.